# remove the inverted quotes from the scraped data using scrapy in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I am trying to **scrape** the data using the Scrapy in python on the demo site quotes.toscrape.com , and then i am trying to store the **scraped** data in the .csv file.

Every thing is working fine but issue is that i want to trim the Inverted quotes from the **scraped** data.

NOTE: I have tried strip('"') with extract method but it is not working. Below is my code.

```
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    item = ProductsItem()
    data_ = response.css("div.quote")
    for items in data_:
        quote = items.css("span.text::text").extract()
        author = items.css("small.author::text").extract()
        tags = items.css("a.tag::text").extract()
        item['quote'] = quote
        item['author'] = author
        item['tags'] = tags
        yield item
```

Comment: The reason that `strip('"')` isn't working is because it is a subtly different character. They are infact `“` and `”`. You can remove these with `strip("\u201c\u201d")`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
import re

def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    item = ProductsItem()
    data_ = response.css("div.quote")
    for items in data_:
        quote = items.css("span.text::text").extract()
        author = items.css("small.author::text").extract()
        tags = items.css("a.tag::text").extract()
        item['quote'] = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',quote) # This is where I modified the code
        item['author'] = author
        item['tags'] = tags
        yield item
```